# How can i compare the catch error.Message to the host string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code:

```
try
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    f = e.Argument as FtpSettings;
    string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", f.Host, f.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : f.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(f.SourceFile));
    if (!UploadPath.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
        UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadPath);
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.UsePassive = f.Passive;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
    long FileSize = new FileInfo(f.SourceFile).Length;
    string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize);
    int ChunkSize = 4096, NumRetries = 0, MaxRetries = 50;
    long SentBytes = 0;
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(f.SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            int BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
            while (BytesRead > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (bw.CancellationPending)
                        return;

                    requestStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead);

                    SentBytes += BytesRead;

                    string SummaryText = String.Format("Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(SentBytes), FileSizeDescription);
                    bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)SentBytes / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                    if (NumRetries++ < MaxRetries)
                    {
                        fs.Position -= BytesRead;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception(String.Format("Error occurred during upload, too many retries. \n{0}", ex.ToString()));
                    }
                }
                BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
            }
        }
    }
    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    er = "The remote name could not be resolved: " + f.Host;
    if (error.Message == "The remote name could not be resolved: " + f.Host)
    {
        ConnectionError = "Error: Please check the ftp address";
    }
}
```

On the bottom i'm doing:

```
if (error.Message == "The remote name could not be resolved: " + f.Host)
```

The problem is that error.Message from example contain:

The remote name could not be resolved: 'ftp.test.comdfdsfdsf'

And f.Host contain:

ftp.test.comdfdsfdsf

In f.Host it's missing the ' '
Or maybe the error.Message have ' '

But they are not the same.

I need this comparison to use later the ConnectionError global variable in Form1 to teel the user that there was a problem with the ftp address.

Comment: Isn't there a narrower exception you can catch? depending on string literals do identify an exception isn't the best way.

Comment: Yuval I tried without the try and catch and i see now that the exception is on the line:  using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) and the exception message is: The remote name could not be resolved: 'ftp.test.comdfdfdsf' so what is the best way to handle it in the catch ?

Comment: Maybe in the catch to do: catch (WebException error) ? since the exception message title is: WebException and then The remote name could not be resolved: 'ftp.test.comdfdfdsf'

Comment: What is the exceptions type?

Comment: This is how the catch look like now: catch (WebException error)
            {
                if (error.Message.Contains(f.Host))
                {
                    ConnectionError = "Error: Please check the ftp address";
                }
            }

Comment: Catching a `WebException` still doesn't guarantee that its a *"remote name could not be resolved"*. Perhaps you'll have to resort to a regex.

Comment: Yuval WebException is the type.

Comment: Do you actually care about which host it is?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this is to narrow it down to the type of exception being thrown and using properties on that.

In this particular case, this is the correct way:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    switch (ex.Status)
    {
        case WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure:
            ConnectionError = "Error: Please check the ftp address";

        case WebExceptionStatus.....
    }
}
```

You don't need to do string comparison at all.